# Can I indicate where my MySQL parameter should go more meaningfully than just having a ? to mark the position - using ODBC connectors and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, parameters, odbc

I've got a chunk of code where I can pass info into a MySQL command using parameters through an ODBC connection.
Example code showing surname passed in using string surnameToLookFor:

```
using (OdbcConnection DbConn = new OdbcConnection( connectToDB ))
{

   OdbcDataAdapter cmd = new OdbcDataAdapter(
   "SELECT Firstname, Address, Postcode FROM customers WHERE Surname = ?", DbConn);

    OdbcParameter odbcParam = new OdbcParameter("surname", surnameToLookFor);
    cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(odbcParam);

    cmd.Fill(dsCustomers, "customers");
}
```

What I'd like to know is whether I can indicate where my parameter should go more meaningfully than just having a ? to mark the position - as I could see this getting quite hard to debug if there are multiple parameters being replaced.

I'd like to provide a name to the parameter in a manner something like this:

```
SELECT Firstname, Address, Postcode FROM customers WHERE Surname = ?surname ",
```

When I try this it just chokes.

The following code

```
    public System.Data.DataSet Customer_Open(string sConnString, long ld) 
    { 
        using (MySqlConnection oConn = new MySqlConnection(sConnString)) 
        { 
            oConn.Open(); 

            MySqlCommand oCommand = oConn.CreateCommand(); 
            oCommand.CommandText = "select * from cust_customer where id=?id"; 

            MySqlParameter oParam = oCommand.Parameters.Add("?id", MySqlDbType.Int32); 
            oParam.Value = ld; 

            oCommand.Connection = oConn; 
            DataSet oDataSet = new DataSet(); 
            MySqlDataAdapter oAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(); 
            oAdapter.SelectCommand = oCommand; 
            oAdapter.Fill(oDataSet); 
            oConn.Close(); 
            return oDataSet; 
        } 
    }
```

is from http://www.programmingado.net/a-389/MySQL-NET-parameters-in-query.aspx
and includes the fragment

```
where id=?id
```

Which would be ideal.

Is this only available through the .Net connector rather than the ODBC?
If it is possible to do using ODBC how would I need to change my code fragment to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice if ODBC had this feature but it doesn't, I'm afraid. I'm speaking of the C API itself here - I don't know if there is a C# layer that adds it. It's not too difficult to write your own wrapper function to implement a simple version of it though.